# Flutter IOS is not showing location permission dialog when using permission_handler package

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, permissions

How can I fix my flutter ios application not showing the permission dialog am currently using permission_handler 10.0.0 package the package works fine in android but on ios the dialog to either grant or deny the permission is not pop-up at all.
Here is the function for the request

```
chkPermissionLoc(ctx) async {
var perLocation = await Permission.location.status;
    if (perLocation.isDenied) {
        await [Permission.location].request();//This isn't running
        print('Permission is Denied');
    } else if (perLocation.isGranted) {
      print('Permission is Granted');
    } else if (perLocation.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      print('Permission is permanently denied');
    } else if (perLocation.isRestricted) {
      print('Permission is OS restricted');
    } else if (perLocation.isLimited) {
      print('Permission is Limited');
    }
}
```

The application simply printed **Permission is Denied** but the function before it which is suppose to show the dialog is not getting called at all.
I have added the string values in the info.plist file as per the documentation in the package but still the same issue.

```
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Permission is Needed</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Permission is Needed 2</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Permission is Needed 3</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Permission is Needed 4</string>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: run pod install for the changes to take effect

Comment: @JabeedAhmed just did from the terminal says **[!] No 'Podfile' found in the project directory**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some code to your podfile as well and for that you can refer [flutter_permission handler in iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEYcU5GtTUs). Just simply copy the code from official documentation and whatever permission you need just uncomment that.

`
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

```
# Start of the permission_handler configuration
target.build_configurations.each do |config|

  # You can enable the permissions needed here. For example to enable camera
  # permission, just remove the `#` character in front so it looks like this:
  #
  # ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
  # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1'
  #
  #  Preprocessor definitions can be found in: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler_apple/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
  config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
    '$(inherited)',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
    # 'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
    # 'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
    # 'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
    # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
    # 'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
    # 'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
    # 'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

    ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
    # 'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
    # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
    # 'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
    # 'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',   

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
    # 'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
    # 'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
    # 'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=1'
  ]

end 
# End of the permission_handler configuration
```

end
end
`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to update the podfile.

1. go into ios folder
2. delete the Podfile.lock file
3. rm -rf Pods
4. pod cache clean --all
5. pod deintegrate
6. pod setup
7. pod install

pod repo update

Hope it helps

Comment: Still the same issue no difference

Comment: delete / uninstall the app from the device and check again

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

        ##Other permissions
        ]
    end
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Request Permission:-

```
    import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

// ...

PermissionStatus status = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();

if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
  // Permission granted, proceed with location-related tasks
} else {
  // Permission denied, handle accordingly
}
```